# android bar sherlock add button

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

again, i'm at loss using action bar sherlock here.. it seems the button I added doesn't appear at all. here's what i already did

in my manifest

```
<activity android:name=".RecipeBookList"  android:theme="@style/SherlockCustom"></activity>
```

and in my styles.xml

```
<style name="SherlockCustom" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="abHeight">25dip</item>
        <item name="abBackground">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="abDisplayOptions">useLogo|showHome|homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
    </style>
```

and in my RecipeBookList.java

```
public class RecipeBookList extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.recipebooklist);

          GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
          gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

          gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                  //Toast.makeText(RecipeBookList.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  displayRecipeList(""+position);
              }
          });
       }

       @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Just a test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
```

aind in my mainmenu.xml

```
<item android:id="@+id/preferences" android:title="Search" android:showAsAction="always|withText" android:icon="@drawable/ab_search"></item>
```

but the search button doesn't appear in the action bar at all.. in fact it doesn't appear anywhere at all. where did i went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the fragment support package provided here: http://beta.abs.io/
Then fix your imports to use the ActionBarSherlock equivelants, and use getSupportMenuInflater() instead of getMenuInflater()

Edit: Should probably mention, this is if you are using ABS4.

Comment: i don't think i'm using ABS4, although I just downloaded ABS, because when I use getSupportMenuInflater it returns "The method getSupportMenuInflater() is undefined". Anyway after I restarted my laptop, the search button appears on the action bar... funny.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //Used to put dark icons on light action bar

    menu.add("Search")
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

    return true;
}
```

Also you have in their page and APK with samples and you can check its code here:
https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/ActionItems.java